# Is this correct reduction?

Tags: grammaticality

We can make reduction for an adverbial clause such as:

Because I was late, I did not go to the party.

To be:

Late, I did not go to the party.

But can we make reduction if the adverbial clause comes in the second position such as:

I did not go to the party because I was late.

To be:

I did not go to the party, late.

Comment: Your first example (adverbial clause of cause) should be reduced to "Being late, I did not go to the party".

Comment: Even your first example is very unlikely to ever be used. “Late, I did not go to the party” sounds very, very odd to me. If someone said it in actual conversation, I would be rather nonplussed and wonder what they meant. Your second example just looks like a mispunctuated way of saying that you went to the party on time and weren’t late. Different examples would be more idiomatic; for example, “In a dreadful hurry, I forgot to check whether I locked the door”. That works. But in yours, a participle would be included in natural speech.

Comment: As I was late, I did not [do whatever].

Comment: Preliminary point: in your first example, "because I was late" is a preposition phrase, not a clause. Your second ex. is marginal -- here, the adjective "late" is a predicative adjunct. Your third ex. is unacceptable, since a predicative adjunct like this works best when located close to its predicand, here "I".

Answer (score 1):

Using the adverb *late* with no grammatical connection to the main clause is not a “reduction” of a subordinate clause, but an entirely different construction: an [*absolute*](https://www.thoughtco.com/absolute-phrase-grammar-1689049). This may not be immediately apparent because *being* or *having been* is frequently omitted in absolute constructions.

> [*Being*]Late, I didn’t go to the party.

Any other verb would be expressed:

> Arriving/Having arrived late, I didn’t go to the party.

There is no inherent reason an absolute can’t come in sentence final position, but in this case, even with the verb expressed, it’s ambiguous:

> I didn’t go to the party, being late.

This could more easily suggest the party started too late for you to attend rather than your late arrival meant you couldn’t go, though the original could also be parsed that way as well.

Your original sentence with the *because* clause is idiomatic and unambiguous. I’d stick with that version.